# I can't get my LazyVGrid to show more than two rows

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

So I've got this very basic grid. It's 5 columns and should have 3 rows.
But I can't get the compiler to compile anything more than two rows....

The compiler complains : 'Extra arguments at positions #11, #12, #13, #14, #15 in call'

If I remove Text 6 to 10 it does compile....

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var columns = [
        GridItem(spacing: 8, alignment: .leading),
        GridItem(spacing: 8, alignment: .center),
        GridItem(spacing: 8, alignment: .center),
        GridItem(spacing: 8, alignment: .center),
        GridItem(spacing: 8, alignment: .center)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 8) {
            Text("Buttons").font(.headline)
            Text("resting").font(.subheadline)
            Text("active").font(.subheadline)
            Text("loading").font(.subheadline)
            Text("disabled").font(.subheadline)

            Text("1").font(.headline)
            Text("2").font(.subheadline)
            Text("3").font(.subheadline)
            Text("4").font(.subheadline)
            Text("5").font(.subheadline)

            Text("6").font(.headline)
            Text("7").font(.subheadline)
            Text("8").font(.subheadline)
            Text("9").font(.subheadline)
            Text("10").font(.subheadline)
        }.padding(.horizontal, 10)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got into `ViewBuilder` 10-views-limit... so as you use static content then you have to wrap some in `Group`/s to fit that rule (ie. no more than 10 views in build block)

So, like

```
var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 8) {
      Group {
        Text("Buttons").font(.headline)
        Text("resting").font(.subheadline)
        Text("active").font(.subheadline)
        Text("loading").font(.subheadline)
        Text("disabled").font(.subheadline)
      }

      Group {
        Text("1").font(.headline)
        Text("2").font(.subheadline)
        Text("3").font(.subheadline)
        Text("4").font(.subheadline)
        Text("5").font(.subheadline)

        Text("6").font(.headline)
        Text("7").font(.subheadline)
        Text("8").font(.subheadline)
        Text("9").font(.subheadline)
        Text("10").font(.subheadline)
      }

      Group {
         ... other code
      }
    }.padding(.horizontal, 10)
}
```

*Note:* `Group` is also view, so there should be no more than 10 groups as well... but groups can contain other groups...

But... of course it is preferable to work with dynamic content, like `ForEach`, just in case.